# Update member value of all instances of Model-based Objects in array?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am enjoying learning Angular2+Typescript and and wondering if there is a way to update all the values of a specific member of all model-based objects in an array, very simply (e.g. one-liner).

For example, say you had this model:

```
export class x1Model{
    status:string = "";
    isAssigned:boolean = false;
    isDefault:boolean = false;
    isRequested:boolean = false;

    constructor(public label:string = ""){}

    toggle():void{
        this.isDefault = !this.isDefault
    }
}
```

And you had this service:

```
export class x1Service{
    x1s = [
        new x1Model("Orange Racer"),
        new x1Model("Wife's Sunday Driver"),
        new x1Model("Weekend Bucket")
    ];

    addX1(x1:x1Model){
        this.x1s = [...this.x1s, x1];
    }

    toggleDefault(x1:x1Model){
        //get index of x1 to set as default
        const x = this.x1s.indexOf(x1);

        //set all as default=false
        set(item.default,false,this.x1s);

        //toggle passed x1 as default
        x1.toggle();

        //update global list
        this.x1s = [
            ...this.x1s.slice(0,x),
            x1,
            ...this.x1s.slice(x+1)                
        ];

    }
}
```

So what I'm wondering is if there is a nifty way to do what I've shown as

```
set("a model's variable", "the new value", "the list of objects of Model type");
```

without having to write a "set" function.

I just think it would be nice if the Model concept could, or is, extended to allow for a quick way to pass an override/update/mask version of one or more variables of a model against any number of objects of that model type, and have the update happen.

Comment: you can just give the **public** accessor to the class members you want to access publicly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite simple with a `forEach`:

```
this.x1s.forEach(x1 => x1.default = false);
```

It reads better then an magic `set` function.

Comment: Thanks, that's is close as I'm going to get, it looks like.  I think it would be great if I could pass a function a masking model that for each k-v-pair in the passed model it would override each object in the passed array appropriately.  I can achieve this already as a nested foreach, but thinking Angular2, the next step would be to make that masking model observable and be able to have active models subscribe to a particular masking model.  As you can imagine, that would allow events that trigger all subscribed objects to be manipulated by a single mask.  I'm sure this is possible somehow.